# Why do I have to use std::string() even for "" to satisfy a template arguments?

Tags: c++, string, templates, c++11

I wrote a very simple template to tokenize a string as shown below.

However, I have a problem calling that function, I cannot use a C string for the `delimiters` or `trim_string` arguments. These have to be `std::string` (or whatever type of string `StringT` is, i.e. `std::wstring`).

So the following fails:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
std::string str = "This string, it will be split, in 3.";
int count = tokenize_string(tokens, str, ",", true, " ");
```

To fix the problem I have to write:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
std::string str = "This string, it will be split, in 3.";
int count = tokenize_string(tokens, str,
                       std::string(","), true, std::string(" "));
```

Is there a way to avoid having to use std::string() around the standard C strings in such a situation?

The errors I get with g++ looks like this:

```
/home/snapwebsites/snapwebsites/snapmanagercgi/daemon/snapmanagerdaemon.cpp: In member function ‘void snap_manager::manager_daemon::init(int, char**)’:
/home/snapwebsites/snapwebsites/snapmanagercgi/daemon/snapmanagerdaemon.cpp:103:71: error: no matching function for call to ‘tokenize_string(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, const string&, const char [2], bool, const char [2])’
         snap::tokenize_string(f_bundle_uri, bundle_uri, ",", true, " ");
                                                                       ^
In file included from /home/snapwebsites/snapwebsites/snapmanagercgi/daemon/snapmanagerdaemon.cpp:35:0:
/home/snapwebsites/BUILD/dist/include/snapwebsites/tokenize_string.h:46:8: note: candidate: template<class StringT, class ContainerT> size_t snap::tokenize_string(ContainerT&, const StringT&, const StringT&, bool, const StringT&)
 size_t tokenize_string(ContainerT & tokens
        ^
/home/snapwebsites/BUILD/dist/include/snapwebsites/tokenize_string.h:46:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/snapwebsites/snapwebsites/snapmanagercgi/daemon/snapmanagerdaemon.cpp:103:71: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘const StringT’ (‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ and ‘char [2]’)
         snap::tokenize_string(f_bundle_uri, bundle_uri, ",", true, " ");
                                                                       ^
```

The template:

```
template < class StringT, class ContainerT >
size_t tokenize_string(ContainerT & tokens
                     , StringT const & str
                     , StringT const & delimiters
                     , bool const trim_empty = false
                     , StringT const & trim_string = StringT())
{
    for(typename StringT::size_type pos(0), last_pos(0); last_pos < str.length(); last_pos = pos + 1)
    {
        pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, last_pos);

        // no more delimiters?
        //
        if(pos == StringT::npos)
        {
            pos = str.length();
        }

        char const * start(str.data() + last_pos);
        char const * end(start + (pos - last_pos));

        if(start != end                 // if not (already) empty
        && !trim_string.empty())        // and there are characters to trim
        {
            // find first character not in trim_string
            //
            start = std::find_if_not(
                  start
                , end
                , [&trim_string](auto const c)
                  {
                      return trim_string.find(c) != StringT::npos;
                  });

            // find last character not in trim_string
            //
            if(start < end)
            {
                reverse_cstring<typename StringT::value_type const> const rstr(start, end);
                auto p = std::find_if_not(
                      rstr.begin()
                    , rstr.end()
                    , [&trim_string](auto const c)
                      {
                          return trim_string.rfind(c) != StringT::npos;
                      });
                end = p.get();
            }
        }

        if(start != end     // if not empty
        || !trim_empty)     // or user accepts empty
        {
            tokens.push_back(typename ContainerT::value_type(start, end - start));
        }
    }

    return tokens.size();
}
```

Comment: What are the types of `tokens` and `str`?

Comment: Try prepending the string with an S or a lowercase s (I forgot how those literals are really) or appending. I'm not sure of the syntax. It's either `S","` or `s","` or `","S` or `","s` (try them and see which doesn't give a syntax error)

Comment: @PaulStelian It's postscript lowercase s, and you need `using namespace std::literals` or something similar.

Comment: @PaulStelian [it's `","s `](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s)

Comment: I totally wasn't aware that there was a namespace usage requirement. Thanks @Brian

Comment: and thanks @RyanHaining

Comment: @PaulStelian, you are correct. That works. Although from what I recall, that does the same thing as `std::string(...)`, it's just using a new feature in C++11 to hide that. Still, I guess that's practical in this situation!

Comment: Um, I think we actually were looking for syntax sugar here, right? :))

Comment: @Brian, I added the `tokens` and `str` definitions to the usage examples. Note that any container that supports `push_back()` and any string type should work.

Comment: What is the error you get?  I'm surprised it doesn't work.  If I knew the error maybe that surprise would go away.

Comment: Wrap the latter two `StringT`s into a non-deduced context, or `int count = tokenize_string(tokens, str, {","}, true, {" "});`, or use `typename ContainerT::value_type` instead.

Comment: @CrazyEddie, I added the output of `g++` wen I do not use `std::string()`.

Comment: @T.C., that was the correct answer! I used `typename ContainerT::value_type` instead of a different type and it works as is. Fantastic!

Comment: No comment about how `string_view` is the future and all?

Comment: @MarcGlisse, I'm not too sure how string_view applies and it is going to be in C++17...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rule is that when you have three `StringT const &` parameters, `StringT` is deduced independently from the corresponding arguments, and the deduced type must match.

You can

- Just use `typename ContainerT::value_type` for all three, if the container's value type is expected to be the correct string type; or
- Block deduction of `StringT` from two of the three `StringT`-taking parameters,

  - Either at the call site by making the later two arguments non-deduced contexts with *braced-init-list*s:

    ```
    int count = tokenize_string(tokens, str, {","}, true, {" "});
    ```
  - Or in the function template itself, by wrapping the latter two `StringT` parameters into a non-deduced context:

    ```
    template < class StringT, class ContainerT >
    size_t tokenize_string(ContainerT & tokens
                         , StringT const & str
                         , typename std::decay<StringT>::type const & delimiters
                         , bool const trim_empty = false
                         , typename std::decay<StringT>::type const & trim_string = StringT())
    ```
- Or take different type parameters for each and harmonize them later in the function template body.

Answer (score 3):

You can use string literals (as suggested by Paul Stelian and others) or you can explicit the first template argument calling `tokenize_string()`.

By example, in this way

```
int count = tokenize_string<std::string>(tokens, str, ",", true, " ");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you allow the delimeter argument to be different from the str argument that your function would work.  Basically it's trying to decide what `StringT` is based on two different types, and of course it can't.  So if you did something like so it should work:

```
template < class StringT,  class DelimT, class TrimT class ContainerT >
size_t tokenize_string(ContainerT & tokens
                     , StringT const & str
                     , DelimT const & delimiters
                     , bool const trim_empty = false
                     , TrimT const & trim_string = StringT())
```

This will allow the compiler to deduce `StringT` as `std::string` and `DelimT` as `char[2]` or whatever for the static strings.

`delimeters` is just used in your call to `find_first_of` and that function will accept the static string...so all should work just fine once you get the compiler to correctly deduce types.  You shouldn't need to convert to `StringT` implicitly or otherwise.

`TrimT` might not need to be separate...you might just leave that as `StringT`.

The other answers are not *wrong*.  They'll all work too.  But I think all you need to do is allow the compiler to deduce two distinct types for these two arguments...and then no specialization or overloads are required.

Comment: This is the 3rd possibility in T.C.'s answer. I may try with that at some point too. Although my strings can be UTF8 or UTF32 as well... so I have to be careful how I compare them against each others.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that TC gave this answer too, minus the detail.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're working with templates. C++ cannot deduce that a string literal (which in data type terms is usually represented as a `const char *`) is meant to be *implicitly converted* to a `std::string` object if you haven't specifically declared the function to take a `std::string` object.

Your best solution is to write two wrapper functions which explicitly define the string type for the first part of the function definition.

```
template <class ContainerT >
size_t tokenize_string(ContainerT & tokens
                     , std::string const & str
                     , std::string const & delimiters
                     , bool const trim_empty = false
                     , std::string const & trim_string = std::string ()) {
    return tokenize_string_detail(tokens, str, delimiters, trim_empty, trim_string); //your original function
}

template <class ContainerT >
size_t tokenize_string(ContainerT & tokens
                     , std::wstring const & str
                     , std::wstring const & delimiters
                     , bool const trim_empty = false
                     , std::wstring const & trim_string = std::wstring ()) {
    return tokenize_string_detail(tokens, str, delimiters, trim_empty, trim_string); //your original function
}
```

I would also consider simply dropping support for `std::wstring`, as it's an incredibly broken attempt at unicode support, and in general, unicode support is better served by the various utilities in boost.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a good solution.  It'll probably work for most cases, but there are a variety of ones in which it won't.  When the user is overriding `char_traits` for example.  Have to remember that `std::string` is an instantiation typedef of `std::basic_string`, a template.

Comment: @CrazyEddie But the user wouldn't be modifying `char_traits` if they're simply passing in string literals. If the goal is to handle string literals without needing to add code cruft to make the compiler accept it, this would work just fine. If they really badly need the wholly generic version of the code visible, then they'd only need to make `tokenize_string_detail` public.

Comment: @Xirema,  thought of specialization, but did not like the idea. As Crazy Eddie is saying, you may have different instantiation (I have a utf32 one, which makes it easier to work on characters when not just working with ASCII). However, T.C. answers was right. I can actually use `typename ContainerT::value_type` and it resolves the issue.